# Add back(close) button to settings with no meny kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How i can add some back or close button to settings with no meny in kivy.
Now i have something like:

[image]

And i wont something like that with back button in top left corner:

[image]

I try do it in .kv file but background not chenge and back button does not appear, my .kv file:

```
<BackButton@Button>:
    pos_hint: {'x':.01,'y':.92}
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    size_hint:(None,None)
    size: (40,40)
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source:"back_icon.png"
<BackgroundWithFlag@FloatLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source:"background.png"
        padding: 80

<SettingsWithNoMenuAndBackButton@SettingsWithNoMenu>:
    BackgroundWithFlag:
        BackButton:
```

Thank  you.

Comment: I don't see any problems, your code works just fine. Did you remember to actually create the `SettingsWithNoMenuAndBackButton`?

Comment: No, i create it.